# how to take substring from last occurance of specific character to end of the string in linux?

Tags: linux, string, bash

I want to to get a sub string something like below script, but it should be usable in Linux bash script.

```
"aa-bbb-cccc-ddd-ee" | awk -F"-" '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer . I used the following scripts in my bash to handle this problem:

command line :

```
stringvar="this text is written to test. tnx"
echo "${stringvar##*. }"
```

bash script :

```
testvar="${line##* }"
echo $testvar
```

output : 
ee

Answer (score 1):

You could use the pattern substitution mode of Parameter expansion in Bash

```
s="aa-bbb-cccc-ddd-ee" echo ${s/*-/}
```

Would print

```
ee
```

Here we substitute the longest match for pattern `*-` with an empty string. The general form of pattern substitution mode for parameter expansion is 
`${parameter/pattern/string}` where pattern is expanded in the same way as in path expressions.